# Leaflet Polyline Arrows

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm currently using leaflet to draw a bunch of lines on a leaflet map using the canvas. However, I'm having issue draw arrows on the lines using canvas.

I have found items such as [polyline decorator](https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.PolylineDecorator) but it very very slow and I only want the arrows to be visible at specified zoom distance (>=13).

How would one do this using leaflet please? I don't have to have repeatable arrows but just a way to show poyline direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know this answer is a little too late but It works with a **good performance** and without any plugin.

You can change the icon(which currently is a triangle arrow(▶)) to any thing you want and its initial direction should be toward right(the zero degree angle).

You can also change the number of arrows to be shown(in this example it's 5)

CSS code :

```
 .arrow-icon {
        width: 14px;
        height: 14px;
    }

        .arrow-icon > div {
            margin-left: -1px;
            margin-top: -3px;
            transform-origin: center center;
            font: 12px/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
```

And here is the Javascript code.The `getArrows` function accepts array of coordinates  of polyline(and optional parameter color and optional parameter number of arrows per line) and returns an array of markers(**just copy and paste everything**) :

```
function getArrows(arrLatlngs, color, arrowCount, mapObj) {

    if (typeof arrLatlngs === undefined || arrLatlngs == null ||    
(!arrLatlngs.length) || arrLatlngs.length < 2)          
    return [];

    if (typeof arrowCount === 'undefined' || arrowCount == null)
        arrowCount = 1;

    if (typeof color === 'undefined' || color == null)
        color = '';
    else
        color = 'color:' + color;

    var result = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < arrLatlngs.length; i++) {
        var icon = L.divIcon({ className: 'arrow-icon', bgPos: [5, 5], html: '<div style="' + color + ';transform: rotate(' + getAngle(arrLatlngs[i - 1], arrLatlngs[i], -1).toString() + 'deg)">▶</div>' });
        for (var c = 1; c <= arrowCount; c++) {
            result.push(L.marker(myMidPoint(arrLatlngs[i], arrLatlngs[i - 1], (c / (arrowCount + 1)), mapObj), { icon: icon }));
        }
    }
    return result;
}

function getAngle(latLng1, latlng2, coef) {
    var dy = latlng2[0] - latLng1[0];
    var dx = Math.cos(Math.PI / 180 * latLng1[0]) * (latlng2[1] - latLng1[1]);
    var ang = ((Math.atan2(dy, dx) / Math.PI) * 180 * coef);
    return (ang).toFixed(2);
}

function myMidPoint(latlng1, latlng2, per, mapObj) {
    if (!mapObj)
        throw new Error('map is not defined');

    var halfDist, segDist, dist, p1, p2, ratio,
        points = [];

    p1 = mapObj.project(new L.latLng(latlng1));
    p2 = mapObj.project(new L.latLng(latlng2));

    halfDist = distanceTo(p1, p2) * per;

    if (halfDist === 0)
        return mapObj.unproject(p1);

    dist = distanceTo(p1, p2);

    if (dist > halfDist) {
        ratio = (dist - halfDist) / dist;
        var res = mapObj.unproject(new Point(p2.x - ratio * (p2.x - p1.x), p2.y - ratio * (p2.y - p1.y)));
        return [res.lat, res.lng];
    }

}

function distanceTo(p1, p2) {
    var x = p2.x - p1.x,
        y = p2.y - p1.y;

    return Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

function toPoint(x, y, round) {
    if (x instanceof Point) {
        return x;
    }
    if (isArray(x)) {
        return new Point(x[0], x[1]);
    }
    if (x === undefined || x === null) {
        return x;
    }
    if (typeof x === 'object' && 'x' in x && 'y' in x) {
        return new Point(x.x, x.y);
    }
    return new Point(x, y, round);
}

function Point(x, y, round) {
    this.x = (round ? Math.round(x) : x);
    this.y = (round ? Math.round(y) : y);
}
```

Then simply draw leaflet polyline(just works for array of `latLng` coordinates not array of array of coordinates):

```
// array of coordinates
var mylatlngs = [
            [55.555, 33.33],
            [..., ...],
            [..., ...],
            [..., ...],
            [..., ...],
            ...
        ];

        var polyline = L.polyline(mylatlngs, { color: 'red' }).addTo(map);
        // draw 5 arrows per line
        L.featureGroup(getArrows(mylatlngs, 'red', 5,map)).addTo(map);
```

Comment: I like the idea. Have an upvote. I think the performance will be the same as PolylineDecorator or worse, and "without any plugin" isn't really an advantage vs copy-pasting about 100 lines, but there is some useful code here, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In [PolylineDecorator](https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.PolylineDecorator) main page
exists link to [Leaflet.TextPath](https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.TextPath), as a lightweight alternative. I assume it is similar with "getArrows" function implementation, that have been proposed early.